# Length Check In Pascal

Tags: exception, pascal, maxlength, string-length

I get the error **Error: Operator is not overloaded** on line 7. Do I have to do a another repeat and can't use the **and** operator?

```
Function GetValidPlayerName : String;
  Var
    PlayerName : String;
  Begin
    Repeat
      Readln(PlayerName);
      If PlayerName = '' And Length(PlayerName) > 10
        Then Write('That was not a valid name.  Please try again: ');
    Until PlayerName <> '';
    GetValidPlayerName := PlayerName;
  End;
```

Comment: Please don't edit the question in a way that will make the already posted answers irrelevant. Now you have created a new bug. Now the program will not quit asking for a name until it is too long... You should follow my example below.

Comment: Sorry. I have edited back to the original code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to write

```
If (PlayerName = '') And (Length(PlayerName) > 10) Then
```

The parentheses are required.

Secondly, this will *always* evaluate to `false`, because there is no string that is both empty and has length 11 or more. Indeed, a string is empty if and only if its length is zero, so basically you say "if the length is zero and the length is 11 or more, then...".

Most likely you wish instead to use a disjunction, that is, to use `or` instead of `and`:

```
If (PlayerName = '') Or (Length(PlayerName) > 10) Then
```

This will display the error message if the name is empty *or* if it is too long.

In addition, the loop will exit even if the name is invalid, because if `PlayerName` is equal to `ThisIsATooLongName` then indeed `PlayerName <> ''`.

What you need is something like

```
Function GetValidPlayerName : String;
Var
  PlayerName : String;
Begin
  Repeat
    Readln(PlayerName);
    If (PlayerName = '') Or (Length(PlayerName) > 10) Then
    Begin
      Write('That was not a valid name.  Please try again: ');
      PlayerName := '';
    End;
  Until PlayerName <> '';
  GetValidPlayerName := PlayerName;
End;
```

or

```
Function GetValidPlayerName : String;
Var
  PlayerName : String;
Begin
  result := '';
  Repeat
    Readln(PlayerName);
    If (PlayerName = '') Or (Length(PlayerName) > 10) Then
      Write('That was not a valid name.  Please try again: ')
    Else
      result := PlayerName;
  Until result <> '';
End;
```

Comment: Then the condition in the while statement has to change too. In the loop the length must not be greater than 10 but the while condition allows any string that is not empty.

Comment: I see, why do the parentheses make a difference?

Also I don't understand why PlayerName needs to be assigned to blank after the error is outputted.

Any explanation is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Jeff: If you write `PlayerName = '' Or Length(PlayerName) > 0` the compiler will attempt to compute the bitwise `or` between `''` and `Length(PlayerName)`, that is, it will assume that you mean `PlayerName = ('' Or Length(PlayerName)) > 0`.

Comment: @Jeff: Because of `Until PlayerName <> ''`. The loop will terminate as soon as `PlayerName` is not the empty string. So if the user enters a too long string, the loop will exit, because a too long string is not empty! You need to make sure that the condition `PlayerName <> ''` is satisfied if and only if you want the loop to exit, that is, if and only if the player name is valid.

Comment: So every time I try to do some kind of validation I should use () for each of the validation rule?

Thanks for all the help you are giving me!

Comment: @Jeff: Every time you want to combine boolean statements using comparison operators like `=`, `<`, `<=`, `<>`, `>`, and `>=` using boolean operators like `and`, `or`, and `xor`, you need to enclose the boolean statements with parenthesis, to get the order of evaluation that you intend.

Answer (score 0):

Urm Im in a similar situation,

```
while(Length(conversionrates[i].rate)<>2)) do
begin
    writeln('the conversion name should be 2 letters. (E.G Pounds to Dollars would be "PD")');
    readln(conversionrates[i].fromto);
end;
```

Wondering if this would work, the program I put this is wont compile.